# How to use spring ExternalRedirectAction? Need to POST to external url in java code and not sure best way

Tags: java, spring, post, httprequest, spring-bean

I am using spring. I want to POST some request param values to an external url.

Here is what I have:

```
public class PageAction extends AbstractAction {
public ActionCode execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) {
    ActionCode code = ActionCode.SUCCESS;

    [I want to set the params in here]

    return code; [<-- I want this to POST to the external url]
}
}
```

And then in xml:

```
<bean name="store/page" class="com...action.PageAction">
    <property name="results">
        <props>
            <prop key="success">[I want the external url here somehow]</prop>
            <prop key="error">error/ErrorPage</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I know how to do this with the "success" being an internal page, but I want it to post the request to an external url.

I've been trying to find an example of ExternalRedirectAction which sounds like what I should use instead, but I can't find an example. There are other classes from AbstractAction as well, but I'm not sure how to implement.

Thanks in advance.